# Improvement for Selection Sort Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, selection-sort

I'm a new student to CS. Right now I'm self-studying Intro to programming. I was studying about Selection Sort Algorithm, and I think that by making this change below to selection sort it is going to make it be more efficient, is this true or I'm missing something??
the change is instead of calling the swap function each time even when there is no change made to the array, we can add changeMade Boolean variable and we use it to call the function only when there is a change made to the array. Please correct me if I'm wrong

```
Declare Integer startScan, i, minValue
Declare Integer minIndex


//the boolean variable
//that could make algorithim
//more efficient 
Declare Boolean changemade

//Declare the array and Declare it is size
//and initialize it
Constant Integer SIZE = 5
Declare Integer array[SIZE]=1, 4, 8, 2, 5

For StartScan = 0 To SIZE-2
    set changeMade = False
    set array[startScan]= minValue
    For i= startScan+1 To SIZE-1
        If array[i]<minValue Then
            set minValue=array[i]
            set minIndex= i
            set changeMade=True //the modification 
        End If
    End For  
    If ChangeMade = True Then
    call swap(array[minIndex], array[startScan])
End For

Module swap(Integer Ref a, Integer Ref b)
    Declare Integer temp
    set temp = a
    set a = b
    set b = temp
End Module
```

Comment: If you look up the implementation of the algorithm, it's actually already like this. The idea is: go through every element, pick the minimum element from the list starting at the current index, if it's not the current element, swap it with the current element. Your `ChangeMade` variable is simply the implementation of checking if the minimum index is the same as the current index.

Comment: Your change *might* be more efficient, but it could be more expensive. If many changes are made during one iteration, you end up having to set the `ChangeMade` flag many times. Perhaps a better optimization would be to replace the `changeMade` check with `If minIndex <> startScan`. You don't need the `changeMade` flag.

Answer (score 2):

Operations such as swap are almost ignored while calculating the complexity.

Although all the operations are taken into account when calculating time complexity. But as loops are dominant compared to other operations, we ignore other operations and only consider dominant operations(Because for large input value, cost of all other operations are much smaller than the dominant operations) .

As an example with selection sort: When you consider all statement costs into account then you get a function f(n)=an2+bn+c (a,b and c are constants and depend on machine architecture). Here dominant term is an2.So we can say Time complexity of selection sort O(an2).We also ignore leading terms coefficient a ,as a does not change the rate of growth.

Have you read about the Asymptotic analysis and notations such as theta, omega, big O. Have a look at them, it will help you get the answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: You are assuming that the quality of the algorithm is only assessed by its asymptotic complexity, which the proposed heuristic does not reduce. Anyway, the heuristic might be good if it speeds-up things in practice, so this deserves being discussed. Asymptotic complexity is not everything.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a false good idea.

This heuristic is effective on elements that are already at the correct position.

Assume there are 10% of them, which can be considered optimistic. While sorting N elements, you will spare 0.1 N swaps but add a large number of assignments to the flag (up to N²/2 !) and N tests of the flag (conditional instructions are very slow).

Unless the swap is really costly, odds are high that the overhead of manipulating the flag will dominate.

---

It is certainly a better idea to drop the flag and test `minIndex != startScan`, but even so, it is unsure that avoiding the swap will counterbalance the extra comparisons.